# Node.js, ajax - Frontend routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm working on a SPA website with node.js, jQuery, mongoose and MongoDB for a shopping website. 
The ajax requests and responses work perfectly when starting from the index.html file. So for example begining on http://localhost:3000 and someone clicks on a link called 'products' I send an ajax request to the the server and the server sends the necessary product information back asynchronously  which lead to http://localhost:3000/products. But the problem is that if someone types http://localhost:3000/products directly in the search bar it will show the json representation of the products.

This is my code:

```js
script.js

function redirect (link) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + link,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            link
        },
        success: function (res) {
            let container = $('#contentToSwap');
            container.html('');
            res.products.forEach(function (products_) {
              ...
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```js
app.js

var Product = require('./models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping');

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    Product.find(function(err, docs) {
        let productChunks = [];
        let chunksize = 4;
        let display = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
            if (docs[i].productType == req.query.link) display.push(docs[i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < display.length; i += chunksize) {
            productChunks.push(display.slice(i, i + chunksize));
        }
        res.send({ products: productChunks });
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

So I need some sort of frontend routing if the user doesn't start at the index.html file. I know that I could write my own router to route the urls correctly and that I could route all requests back to the index.html like

```js
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

But then I cannot load all the necessary product information from the server when someone clicks a link. So I'm a little bit confused on hwo to tackle this issue. Any help is appreciated

Comment: try to change the `type: 'GET'`  to `type: 'POST'`

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved by separating api routes from normal ones by adding specific url prefixes such as `/api` for all routes that return json data. What you can do is to specify `/api/whatever-you-want`, make it the target for your ajax call and place it above `app.get('*' ...`.

Since routes and middleware functions are resolved top to bottom, it will be matched by your ajax call only, leaving the `/products` unaffected.

**answer to question -- Is it possible to redirect user from /api/products to /product if the request wasn't generated by ajax?**

Yes, it is possible by adding request query parameter to ajax call which will not be present on normal call and then check those on the server side and decided what to do if it (that specific query parameter) is missing or not.

Let's assume some client side JS that generates ajax call.

```js
fetch('/api/products?api=true')
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Notice the request url - `/api/products?api=true`

Now assume a normal call from html file.

```
<a href="/products">products</a>
```

These two calls differ in that `api` query parameter (ajax call has it, the other one doesn't).

And for the server side part of the task -- request query parameters object can be accessed via `query` property on request object (`req.query`).

```js
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.api) {
        // if get request doesn't contain api param. then
        // handle it accordingly, e.g. do redirect
        return res.redirect('/products');
    }

    // request comming from ajax call, send JSON data back
    res.json({ randomStuff: 'abcd' });
});
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick, works perfectly like this. Is it possible to redirect users which might accidently try to visit an '../api/whatever' url? For example when they try to reach app/api/products to redirect them to app/products?